# Format hovertext or hoverinfo information in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

How can I format the `hoverinfo()` or `hovertext()` of my grouped plotly barchart in order to display the data as the following:

```
Animals:Giraffe
SF_ZOO:20

Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)
library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF_ZOO',marker=list(color="#556361"),
               hoverinfo = paste(Animals,SF_Zoo))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA_ZOO',marker=list(color="#A72608"),
                         hoverinfo = paste(Animals,SF_Zoo))

fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')

fig
```

Alternatively I could use `ggplotly()` solution.

Comment: Have you tried HTML tags? This is also working with `ggplotly()`

Comment: no how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hovertemplate`:

```
library(plotly)

Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)
library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(
  data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF_ZOO', 
  marker=list(color="#556361"), 
  hovertemplate = paste("Animals: %{x}" , "<br>SF_Zoo: %{y}", "<extra></extra>")
)
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
  y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA_ZOO',marker=list(color="#A72608"),
  hovertemplate = paste("Animals: %{x}" , "<br>LA_Zoo: %{y}", "<extra></extra>")
)

fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')

fig
```

Comment: thanks u can post it here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848027/hovertemplate-shows-data-twice-when-used-with-add-trace-in-plotly

Answer (score 2):

```
Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo) %>% pivot_longer(cols = contains("Zoo")) %>% 
  mutate(label=paste0("<b>", name, "</b><br>", Animals))

gg <- ggplot(data, aes(y=value, x=Animals, fill=name, text=label)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
ggplotly(gg, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]